# designing layouts programatically for multiple screen sizes

Tags: android

I would like to know how to create an android UI designs for multiple screen sizes programatically?

Take for example a Button or Layout set for 3.5inch programatically using width and height will look very small in 5inch device
similarly Button or layout created for 5 inch device will get trimmed for 3.5 inch device.

So would like to know how to handle it

Answer (score 2):

Use Density pixels (dp) instead of pixels.

read here [android supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Is use these helper methods to convert between density pixels and real pixels :

```
/**
 * Converts dp unit to equivalent pixels, depending on device density. 
 * 
 * @param dp A value in dp (density independent pixels) unit. Which we need to convert into pixels
 * @return float value to represent px equivalent to dp depending on device density
 */
public static float dpToPixel(float dp){
    Resources resources =  MyApplication.getAppContext().getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float px = dp * (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
    return px;
}

/**
 * Converts device specific pixels to density independent pixels.
 * 
 * @param px A value in px (pixels) unit. Which we need to convert into db
 * @return float value to represent dp equivalent to px value
 */
public static float convertPixelsToDp(float px){
    Resources resources =  MyApplication.getAppContext().getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float dp = px / (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
    return dp;
}
```

(MyApplication is a class that extends the Application class)

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
```

Answer (score 0):

android supports the variety of screen sizes, and resolutions in a very good fashion.
you can provide different layouts to different screen sizes by using the smallest width qualifier.

you can also provide different versions of each image/icon for each screen density.

check Deacoy's link for further information. 
Always remember the best way to start diving into a new technology is the official documentation.